# iOS alignment lost in merging tentative definition

Tags: iphone, ios, alignment, definition

when I archive my iOS app I get the following errors:

```
ld: warning: alignment lost in merging tentative definition _isDragging
ld: warning: alignment lost in merging tentative definition _isLoading
```

Could someone please tell me what's wrong and where should I look for...

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously this is happening just to me... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue.  I'm assuming that _isDragging and _isLoading are global variables that you declared somewhere.  If that is so, make sure you declare both as `extern` in your .h file thusly:

MyFile.h

```
extern bool _isDragging;
extern bool _isLoading;
```

MyFile.m

```
bool _isDragging = false;
bool _isLoading = false;`
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have this variables defined int two different .m files. I have added extern declaration in .h file with no luck. So I tried to initialize those two variables in .m files like that: extern BOOL isDragging = NO; and extern BOOL isLoading = NO; Now the warning is gone. How can I make a global variable for just one class not the whole project? Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be doing the right thing.  If you declare a global variable in the .m file (and not include it in the corresponding .h file) only the code in the .m file (ie. the code for a single class) will see the variable.